# What are corresponding directories on Android for common Linux pathnames?

Tags: c++, linux, android-ndk, porting, rooted-device

I'm porting the C++ `myToll` Linux application to run on Android using NDK r10d.  (Note this is not an Android app with an `apk`, but a utility tool to run from the shell.)  This is a command line interface and has no GUI and is being built as a standalone application with the NDK.

On Linuxes such as Centos 5, the tool reads and writes to the following standard directory locations:

```
/var/run/myTool/   (read/write)
/var/log/myTool/   (read/write)
/etc/myTool/       (read only)
/tmp/              (read-write)
```

The `myTool` is installed in `/system/xbin/myTool` and can run on a rooted android phone as a utility from the shell, but fails to access these same locations at runtime, even when run as `root`.

What would be the corresponding locations to use on an android system that the `myTool` will have sufficient permissions to write too and is where such files would common be expected to be found on Android?  Are there any locations that can be created by `root` such that `myTool` can use them at runtime without being `root`?

Comment: There are no corresponding locations - Android is not designed to support 3rd party command line tools (or anything other than apk's), so anything you do will be fully custom.  Normally, the only "unix-style" filesystem which a 3rd party app has access to is the package's own private storage directory, though who knows what you will encounter on a root-hacked device.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46926/android-folder-hierarchy) about file hierarchy for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the [Android stackexchange answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/46934/542) offered by ferzco, I settled on the following solution that works on my rooted Samsung Galaxy S4:

```
/var/run/myTool/  =>  /data/log/myTool/run/
/var/log/myTool/  =>  /data/log/myTool/log/
/etc/myTool/      =>  /etc/myTool/
/tmp/             =>  /data/local/tmp/myTool/
```

I used `/data/log/myTool` as the base for two of the directories and `/data/local/tmp` for a third because they were the only ones I could find that offered write permission to `myTool` when not `su`(ed) to `root`.  I needed `root` to set up the `myTool` subdirectories during installation, but once the `myTool` directories are created and `chmod 777 myTool` as `root`, the user no longer needs to be `root` to write to those subdirectories.  For the fourth, `/etc/myTool`, because `myTool` only needs to read information from `/etc` at runtime, I left it in the existing `/etc` directory since it was readable (although not writable) by the user once created and I was able to configure it as required up front as `root`.

Comment: This is really not a good way to do things, both because it requires breaking the security model, and because it makes unsafe assumptions about directory structure on a device - something that *has* changed with Android versions, and doubtless will again.  You should put everything under your app's data folder, the path of which you should be discovering at runtime.  Within that folder, you can create whatever subdirectory layout you like.  Likely you should install the executable itself there as well (normally the only place an app could write to), so it can find the rest relative to itself.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree with your concerns in general, but in my situation, these are acceptable trade-offs given the controlled situation I am running in (e.g. not widely nor publicly distributed).  The `myApp` is installed in `/system/xbin/myApp` to run as a utility and is present in the default `PATH` for my phone.

Comment: If you are installing it as part of the Android build, that can make a bit more sense - though referring to it as an "app", while not incorrect in the general sense, invites confusion with a typical android package.  That said, be very careful about 777 permission - it is hardly ever the right setting.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Please suggest a better way to refer to it than as an `app` and I will edit to clarify.

Comment: I'd probably call it a tool or simply program, but it's okay at this point as you've chosen a course of action and probably aren't going to get a lot more interest in this question.  Another thing to keep in mind is that even with command line tools, there can be a difference between those you intend to install via adb for use by the adb shell user, vs those packaged with an Android app for use by that app's unix user.